# NETCONF Event Notifications client support for RFC 5277 for a mount point in south bound

Tags: opendaylight

Does ODL controller have client support for receiving NETCONF Event Notifications(RFC  5277) from a mounted netconf server?

If so, do we have any documentation on usage with REST API?

How does it handle notification? Will it write all notification message to a database where user can retrieve?